# requirejs-config.js compiling with wrong code

Tags: magento-2.1, requirejs

Magento 2.1.4 with an nginx setup creates an extra line of code  in `pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js` after compiling the static content:

```
require.config({"baseUrl":"http:///pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US"});
```

I am using a custom theme, and not using Luma.  And I have no references to Luma in the magento install.  This code sets my base URL wrong and creates lots of bad URLs in the admin, thus admin does not work.  If I delete the line of code the URLs load fine, and admin works.

If I compile the static files on an apache server, the requirejs-config.js compiles without that line of code, and everything works.

What would be making this code appear?  Where would the code be coming from as I do not have any Luma references?